# Browser Not Rendering CSS ID Style (Override Shows Correct in Firebug)

Tags: css

I have a link where I have set the ID to have a color FB0026. The link sits within a div class with CSS to set it another color (grey).

The ID should have a greater weight anyway, but even if I set FB0026 as !important the end result is the color set in the div (grey), and not the specified style from the ID.

```
.tune-in a {color: #dfdfdf;}            
a#nowplaying:link {color:#FB0026;}
```

It works in the simplified [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pZFTx/)

Trouble shooting in firebug isn't helping me as the div css is shown as being correctly overridden, with the  style in the clear. However if I un-check the struck out CSS it renders correctly.

The full css can be found [here](http://www.budgiecollective.com) behind the #NOWPLAYING link in the top black bar.

Many thanks.

Comment: I showed the simplified version to demonstrate what I want to achieve. You can see the problem on the site link from the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you have visited the link.

Test this yourself by clearing your history and refreshing your page. Your link will be red again. Click on it, and it will be grey.

The colour is red for `:link` which is fine until you visit it. Once that happens, since you have no `:visited` rules, it grabs the styling from `.tune-in a` instead.

If you remove `:link` from `a#nowplaying:link` it will remain red even after visiting the link.

Comment: Ha ha. Such a simple solution. And makes perfect sense now that you point it out. Thank you!